# RSpec - set 'files_or_directories_to_run' option to load spec from outside Rails.root

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

I am trying to load a spec file/directory that is not part of the current rails project (shared specs i use in serveral projects).

I already came to the point that there is an option called `files_or_directories_to_run` in Rspec config which defaults to `spec` dir.
With hacking around in the Rspec source code I also managed to get the required behavoir by hard coding the dir paths inside.

unfortunatly, i found no way to achieve this in a clean way.

I tried putting `-- files_or_directories_to_run 'path/one'` in the `.rspec`file,
i also tried to use `RSpec.configure`, where i have access to the `files_or_directories_to_run=` method, but in the end, all these options seemed to be ignored.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

So, after digging around a lot in the Rspec Core code, i realized that the `files_or_directories_to_run` will always be populated by the command line args given to the rspec command - calling `rspec path/to/one path/to/other` results in `files_or_directories_to_run` to be `["path/to/one", "path/to/other"]`

sometimes its that simple...